# Does extension background script stop running when closing the browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser, background

I have several searches that it said background script stop running when the extension is disabled or uninstalled. But it does not mention if background script also stop running when the browser closed. So I just want to clarify this.

Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: See [Declare permissions > background](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/declare_permissions/#background)

Comment: And https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=chrome%20%22Continue%20running%20background%20apps%20when%20Google%20Chrome%20is%20closed%22

Comment: @ThomasMueller thanks for your reference. So it will be controlled by user's settings that allow background script running when browser is closed or not.